# stop recording in service android

Tags: java, android

I have an application, in which it runs a service. This service includes two things:
-Getting readings from bluetooth.
-Record audio file.

For recording, I am using the code posted by : http://www.androiddevblog.net/android/android-audio-recording-part-2

I found this link in one of the questions already posted in this website. If you can check the code, you will find that there are two main functions for recording: startrecording(), and stoprecording().

There is an activity "main_activity" with start and close buttons. the start button enables the service, and calls the startrecording function, and gets the readings from the oximeter.

My question is: where should I call the stoprecording function? in the destroy() function of the service? within the close button in the "main_activity"?

I have tried both. In the first way, stoprecording function does not finish, i,e, recording generates raw file, and stoprecording copy it and convert it to wav file.

in the second way, the button hangs :S

your help is appreciated

thanks,
Toleen